# PDF Merging Two Files With Same Name

Tags: pdf, merge

I have two folders of pdfs with 500 pdfs in each, all with identical filenames.  Is there a way for a novice like myself to batch merge leaving me with one folder and 500 merged pdfs?  I need the pdf named robot.pdf to merge with the other pdf named robot.pdf and so on.  Can this be automated?

Thank you, appreciate the help here.

*EDIT*  Using Windows 7

I have two folders, FOLDER 1 and FOLDER 2.  Both have pdfs named 1.pdf, then 2.pdf, then 3.pdf, all the way to 500.pdf.  I need to be able to batch merge these folders, so there is one folder with both 1.pdfs merged, then both 2.pdfs merged, etc.

Sorry, my question was vague.  I do have pdftk downloaded

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can not be names exactly the same, or if they were they could not be in the same directory. But anyways, if you are on mac or linux, install pdftk with your package manager. After that, run

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output out.pdf
```

If they are in separate directories, use a find command in place of *.pdf, otherwise just make sure you're in the directory with the pdfs before running the command.

EDIT
You said they were in separate directories, then just run

```
pdftk $(find . -name robot.pdf) cat output out.pdf
```

If they have different names, then modify the command as needed, or do it with *.pdf as the -name, but that may include unwanted files.

Comment: Thank you, just added more to the question to help better explain the issue...